# Referring to the one-dimensional or second dimensional part of a 2D array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Is there a specific name you use when referring to the 1st or 2nd dimensional part of a 2D array? Or, do you just refer to it as: "the first dimensional part", or something along those lines?

Comment: I don't think there's a universal name for it. Often "row" and "column" applies. Sometimes "x" and "y". It depends somewhat on the kind of data (image, matrix, table).

Comment: I don't use it much but as Paul Hankin also comments, row/column seems to describe it well. Also notice the Row/Column major order used to describe how data is organized in a 2D array. C is row-major. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order

Comment: In K&R, the terms used are: 1) **row and column subscripts**, 2) the **rightmost subscript**, and 3) the **first dimension subscript**. So the only thing they were consistent about is the word "subscript". Personally, I use row/column index, or first/second dimension. In other words, the answer is *something along those lines*. Choose what works for you.